# Best OAuth flow to allow customers to access my SaaS application

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, saas

I have a SaaS application that has multiple organisations and each organisation has multiple users.  Each customer is an organisation (not a user) and the customer wants access to their data in my SaaS application via API.  Obviously I need to authenticate the customer so they only receive the data that belongs to their organisation.

The customer will be importing this data from their application so this is a server-to-server API call which I assume I need to use `client credentials` flow.

The customer will be able to generate the credentials on a self-service basis.

Is using `client credentials` flow the correct flow?

If using `client credentials` flow does each customer have their own `client_id` and `client_secret` or does my application have 1 `client_id` and each customer have their own `client_secret`?

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution for this type of B2B API solution is to use Client Credentials flow as you suggest.

- Each business parter uses their own client id for identification when calling your API
- Each partner is also given a string client secret - though it may be possible if your authorization server supports it to use secrets based on an X509 credential
- Use of different client ids enables you to turn off Partner A without impacting PArtner B - and also to tell callers apart

Authentication completes based on the client id and secret being verified and you then move onto authorization. Typically your API will need to continue by doing this:

- Receive a technical client id such as 08134scdv79
- Map it to an application specific id, such as a primary key from your Partners database table
- Authorize the request based on whether the caller is allowed to get the data requested

The one interesting aspect to your question is the self service part. I assume you mean some kind of administrator from a business partner can set up credentials - but that this remains a restricted operation?